# Android How to preload/package data files in Android in /data/data/app_package_name/files directory?

Tags: android, java-native-interface, android-ndk

I am interested in loading a bunch of data TEXT files which will then be read in by a JNI C++ code.  So I need to place preload these files somewhere from which the JNI C++ code can read them. I am open to other suggestions about where to place these files but they need to be read accessible without using for example AssetManager ResourceManager etc since I am reading from C++ side. I also don't want to write them just preload the files as resources and then read them.  I did find this solution: http://blog.sephiroth.it/2010/10/24/reading-resource-files-from-native-code/ which uses the libzip c library to read the apk.  Really looking for the best way.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Store them as resources, and write them out when the applications first runs using Java code. You can then access them as normal files from native code. Another place where you could write them is external storage (SD card).

Comment: How accessible is the SD card? % how many devices have SD cards, and and will allow app to be installed that needs SD card?  I don't need to extra space and don't want user to do any extra acceptance of the app.

Comment: So you don't think c can access directory in resource folder?

Comment: ok.  it can't there is one more approach outlined here: http://blog.sephiroth.it/2010/10/24/reading-resource-files-from-native-code/

Comment: If your files are relatively small, you don't need to use the SD card, internal storage would do. Most devices (with Android Market, at least) should have external storage, even if it is not a physical SD card. As for accessing resource folders from C, it depends. If you functions expect a regular FILE* pointer, no. If you can use  NDK APIs to read out the resources and pass them as blobs, yes.

Comment: ok.  well I have seen some reports of crashing using the ziplib approach.  So I think I will go with what you suggest.

Comment: I have written the files but when I try to read them it indicates file is open.

Comment: I am closing fos, buffered writer etc before I try to read in C++